# WinterCMS/ OctoberCMS builder - sorting product in categories

Tags: sorting, plugins, builder, octobercms

I built the plugin (with builder) where I have products and categories. Product and categories are "conected" by relation table. I have list of products and another list of categories. On page where I list my all categories everthing works fine. The problem is with the single category view. Now products in a single category are listed by add order. But I want to have my own order of products or some sort of reordering. Builder delivers sorting in record list (categories page) but not in record details (single category page).
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you have already added relationship like `category <-> products`
Here you can add an `order` option to set the order.

```php
// inside category model
public $hasMany = [
    'products' => [
        \Acme\Shop\Models\Product::class,
        'order' => 'title desc', // <- here although its hardcoded
    ]
];
```

> Or if you prefer dynamic order then inside your page `code` section you can add the `onStart` function and fetch the product manually.

```php
function onStart() {
    $id = 1; // just for example you can get category based on slug
    $sortedProducts = Category::find($id)
         ->products()->orderBy('title')->get();
    // dynamic as per your need  ^
    $this['products'] = $sortedProducts;
}

// now in the code section you can use `products` and they will be sorted
```

if any doubt please comment